# MATLAB: Global Optimization where one parameters has to be an odd integer

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to find the global minimum of a function `f` that takes two parameters `a` and `b`. While `a` is continuous, `b` has to be an odd integer. How can I approach this problem, given MATLAB's built in functions and those that come with the Optimization and Global Optimization Toolboxes?

Comment: In general a global optimum cannot be achieved. Do you have any extra conditions on `f`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "extra conditions"? I have lower and upper bounds for `a` and `b`, but that's it. In the actual application, `b` is the (centered) window of a smoothing function, if that helps. If it makes things easier, I could probably re-program my smoothing function so that it takes any integer and calculates the window `x-n:x+n`.

Comment: E.g. if f is not continous in a you have no chance (in the general case) to find a global optimum since it could be "everywhere", even not existant. For continous it exists of course, but to guarantee the minimum to be findable you need some extra conditions like convexity or (known) finite number of local minima or similar...

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for your explanation. I'm relatively sure my objective function is convex and I'm actually not even sure if it has local minima at all (I'm trying to optimize parameters of a model, so I don't know for sure). Apart from that, what MATLAB function would be suitable for my problem (only using (odd) integers for parameter `b`)?

Comment: Well, the last time I checked, if n is ANY integer, then 2n-1 is always an odd integer. So really, the constraint is that one of your parameters be integer. There are mixed NLP tools to be found on the file exchange, that allow some parameters to be forced to integer.

Comment: Ah yes using that would obviously be easier than reprogramming my smoothing algorithm. I guess mixed NLP is the keyword I was missing, thank you.

Comment: The ones I recall are fminconset and minlp. There are probably others since I've looked.